# Sending eMail with smtp in Delphi 4

Tags: email, delphi, smtp, indy

I want to send emails with smtp in a Delphi4 program. It works in delphi 6 with indy.

Is there a indy-package for delphi 4 ?

Is there another way to send emails with smtp in delphi 4 ?

thanks for all informations

Lucia

Comment: Wasn't Delphi 4 released in 1998?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand yes, it was

Comment: Write a DLL with a newer version than Delphi 4 and call its function for sending mails from your app.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a indy-package for delphi 4 ?

Technically yes, Indy does still include project files for Delphi 4. <sup>1</sup> But, you will have to compile and install them manually, Indy won't automate that for you.  And I offer no guarantees about whether they actually work.

Delphi 4 is almost 25 years old, so don't expect much support if something goes wrong. Even Delphi 6 support is questionable, and Delphi 5 support is really pushing it. <sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup>: Note that all support for pre-2009 Delphi/C++Builder versions will be dropped in Indy 11, including project files.

<sup>2</sup>: Delphi 5 is about as far back as I'm usually willing to go on support, since I never had a Delphi version earlier than that. And even then, this is only because C++Builder 5 had bugs that affected some of Indy's method signatures, which were fixed in later versions.  But do feel free to ask questions if needed, and I will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

ICS version 5 is still available from archive. It supports Delphi 1 up to Delphi 7. Look at http://wiki.overbyte.eu/wiki/index.php/ICS_Download.

Don't expect much support although I will do my best to help you (I have no Delphi 4 available anymore).